# leaflet - change routing vehicle when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, leaflet, routing

I want to change the routing vehicle when clicked on a button. The default routing vehicle is "car" ("auto") when clicked a button routing vehicle should change to "foot" ("pedestrian").

I am using leaflet.easy.button and leaflet.routing.machine plugins, as routeservice I use mapzen.

**Links:**

- leaflet.routing.machine:
  https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine
- leaflet.easy.button:
  https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton
- mapzen:
  https://github.com/mapzen/lrm-mapzen

**My code:**

1. Routing.control :

   ```
   var myRouter = L.Routing.control({
       router: L.Routing.mapzen('valhalla-ABCDEFG', {
           costing:"auto"}),
       routeWhileDragging: true,
       geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
       formatter: new L.Routing.mapzenFormatter()
   }).addTo(map);
   ```
2. Easy.Button :

   ```
   L.easyButton('<img src="pic.png">', function(btn,map){
       myRouter.route({costing: "pedestrian"});
   }).addTo(map);
   ```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Or maybe a different way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `route` method does not pass any options on to the router. You'll want to use the `getRouter` method to set the router options first. Then you can recalculate using `route`:

```
L.easyButton('<img src="pic.png">', function(btn,map){
  myRouter.getRouter().options.costing = "pedestrian";
  myRouter.route();
}).addTo(map);
```